# Blender 2.8 (crash)

Tags: blend-files

My blender 2.8 29th august 32 bit version is not opening .
whenever i try to open it, it crashes.
Please help me figure it out
.
Do anybody have a way to solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dont Worry it can happen because the 2.8 is still in development phase.